# Facebook ID Matching API says invalid token

Tags: facebook, firebase, facebook-graph-api

I have an app in firebase where the user logs in with Facebook. From that login I get his `ASID`. Now I want to get this users ID in my messenger and write him a message.

I followed this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching

My URL looks something like this:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/{ASID}/ids_for_apps?access_token={pageAccessToken}&appsecret_proof={sha256}

To get the `pageAccessToken`:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/{pageId}?fields=access_token&access_token={userAccessToken}

Now I get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Invalid token. Can only query using page access tokens where the page is owned by the same business as the app.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "ACv6_We47HagGtMBzrQuT5A"
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

In the developer page for my App, I have linked the sites (Settings > Extended > App Pages)

Comment: _“where the page is owned by the same business as the app”_ - have you performed the necessary steps in that regard?

Comment: I have just realized yesterday, that it is not enough to connect the App and Page via the connection inside the app, but you rather have to create a business Page. This is undocumented information and hard to find for someone with no prior connection with facebook. But thanks for the hint. @04FS